# Do all the buyable crates give the same amount of crafting parts?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2-2017

The crates in battle front 2 kind of suck because after a player unlocks a fair number of cards that player usually gets mostly duplicate cards.   However, the crafting parts received from the crate mean that the player can eventually save up and unlock the cards they want.  I started buying the cheapest crates, the hero crates, because I didn't really care about the cards themselves.  Since the cards are mostly dupes, I really only care about the crafting parts and money.
But I can't recall if I checked the number of crafting parts when I switched to only hero crates, which gives 50 parts if I recall correctly.  Also the devs may have altered the number of parts, but probably not.

That makes me wonder if there is any advantage to buying the other crate types in terms of crafting parts, especially since you already receive cards from the other categories in each crate type.

Do any of the buyable crate types give a different amount of crafting parts? or do all of the buyable crates contain 50 parts each?

Comment: Jeez downvote? I honestly want to know the answer.

Comment: I think they are the same over the 3 crates. Hero craters are the most cost effective in my eyes. It's what I do anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All buyable crates contain either 35 or 50 crafting parts at random as of the time of this writing.**

The player gets 35 crafting parts for receiving 5 cards and 50 when they get 4 cards, as far as I can tell.

Which means that it is probably in the player's best interest to only buy the cheapest crate, the hero crate, because duplicate cards become quite common from any crate.  Therefore the crafting parts are the only truly valuable part of the crate experience after most of the initial cards are unlocked.  Yes, you can get lucky and receive higher level cards, but duplicates cards are usually still more common than not even at, perhaps especially at, the higher levels.